# Keyword extraction: same word in plural/singular/past_tense/-ing format

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

When extracting keywords from a text, I realized that I get back mostly the same words in different formats. Is there a way to enable the same word to show up only once?

> **Example:** updated updates update updating | research researched researchers | files filed
>   file

Code: Summa (TextRank) package used here:

```
k_words = keywords.keywords((str(document)), words=10, ratio=0.2, language='english')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stem and lemmatize the text before doing any work on it (also, remove stop words and punctuation). NLTK has built-in lemmatizers and stemmers, of which you can use:

#### For stemming:

```
import nltk

from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

porter = PorterStemmer()

print(porter.stem("cats"))  #  =>  cat
print(porter.stem("trouble"))  #  =>  troubl
print(porter.stem("troubling"))  #  =>  troubl
print(porter.stem("troubled"))  #  =>  troubl
```

> From [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com):
>
> "Stemming is the process of reducing inflection in words to their root forms such as mapping a group of words to the same stem even if the stem itself is not a valid word in the Language."

#### For lemmatization:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize("has")  #  =>  has
wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize("was")  #  =>  wa
```

> From [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com):
>
> "Lemmatization, unlike Stemming, reduces the inflected words properly ensuring that the root word belongs to the language. In Lemmatization root word is called Lemma. A lemma (plural lemmas or lemmata) is the canonical form, dictionary form, or citation form of a set of words."

You can read more about Stemming and Lemmatization with Python NLTK in [this article](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/stemming-lemmatization-python).